# The field with Id {GUID} defined in feature {GUID} was found in the current site collection or in a subsite

Tags: solution-package

I am not the developer and I need to deploy a solution by add-SPsolution with WSP file. I don't have Visual Studio to make change like Overwrite="TRUE"

During my first deploy, everything goes fine except the page loading the custom solution (a user control) throw error.

So I tried to Deactivate the solution in Site settings -> site collection solution. Then re-activate again to find the titled error..

What can I do? Do you think remove entire site collection and re-create can fix?

Comment: Have you tried deleting said field ? Make sure it's not actually used before doing that though. You can access the field edit page like this on your site/web : mysiteurl/_layouts/15/fldedit.aspx?fieldId=465a07bb-bb4f-4ec5-8ff9-e4c54f6d726b and replace with your field id

Comment: Cameron, I got error for the url after replaced my fieldID. Like "Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentException: Invalid field name. "

Comment: Hmm, using an invalid GUID throws a field not found kind of error so that's not it. Are you using SP2010 or SP2013 ? I tested this on SP2013

Comment: was this the error http://jshidell.com/2014/01/07/how-to-fix-system-argumentexception-invalid-field-name-guid-when-trying-to-access-a-sharepoint-2010-listdocument-library/ ? Are you sure you used query string parameter FieldId and not Field ?

Comment: I delete the site collection and start everything from new. It seems work around the issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete the site collection and start everything from new. It seems work around the issue.